# SQL Problem : Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an issue in query.  I have tables `product`, `stockRecord` and `priceDetail`.  I want to display all products.  If the price is not defined in `priceDetail` for that product, then it will be 0.00; similarly if the quantity is not defined in `stockRecord` table, then the quantity should be 0.

But if the price is defined in the `priceDetail` table, then we should get the latest price from the table

#### WMProduct

```
  BusinessUnit   ProductCode    Description    SalableFlag
  MASS           0001           Pen            1
  MASS           0002           Computer       1
  MASS           0003           Book           1
  MASS           0004           Bottle         1
```

#### WMStockRecord

```
 ProductCode     AvailableQuantity
 0001            10
 0003            15
```

#### WMPriceDetail

```
 ProductCode   DateFrom      DateTo        Price
 0001          10-10-2009    10-10-2011    100
 0001          10-12-2009    10-10-2010    80
 0001          12-12-2010    01-12-2011    120
 0002          12-01-2010    ''            200
 0004          12-12-2010    12-05-2011    100
```

I need list of products like this:

```
BusinessUnit  ProductCode   Description SalableFlag   Price    AvailableQuantity
MASS          0001          Pen         1             120      10
MASS          0002          Computer    1             200      0
MASS          0003          Book        1             0.00     15
MASS          0004          Bottle      1             0.00     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using sub query and left join like below :

```
SELECT P.ProductCode AS ProductCode, 
       P.Description AS ProductName,  
       P.SalableFlag AS Salable,
       ISNULL(STK.AvailableQuantity, 0) AS Qty,
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM WMPriceDetail
               WHERE ProductCode = P.ProductCode ORDER BY DateTo DESC), 0) AS Price 
  FROM WMProduct P
  LEFT JOIN WMStockRecord STK ON P.ProductCode = STK.ProductCode
```